# replace tooltip(bootstrap) text by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the text of a bootstrap tooltip button when the actual button is clicked and then after the mouse is not over the button to back dynamically the default text of the tooltip. I have trouble with jquery code. May someone explain to me how the things are working. My idea is to check first if the button is clicked and then if it is to show(change the default tooltip message) then when the mouse is no longer over the button or the button is not clicked to show the of tooltip message but I cannot put the things in my head how it is going to be structured. 
Any advice is more than welcome.

here is my code until now.

```js
$(function() {
 var $toolTip = $('#tooltip-example');
 $toolTip.tooltip();

 $toolTip.click(function(){
  $myToolTip.attr('title', 'New Hello World Message').tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
 });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="tooltip-example" data-tooltip title="Hello world">Click me</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below.

The only issue i can see in your example is that **$myToolTip** is not defined , you must meant **$toolTip**.

Another problem with in SO snippet was the position of the button at the screen top, this was causing  the tooltip to be not displayed properly, i changed the tooltip direction to bottom to fix it.

```js
$(function() {
  var $toolTip = $('#tooltip-example');
  var originalTitle = $toolTip.attr('title');
  $toolTip.tooltip({placement: "bottom"});

  $toolTip.click(function() {
    $toolTip.attr('title', 'New Hello World Message').tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
  });
  
  $(document).on("mouseout","#tooltip-example",function()
  {
    $toolTip.attr('title',originalTitle).tooltip('fixTitle').tooltip('show');
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="tooltip-example" data-tooltip title="Hello world">Click me</button>
```

Comment: yes, thank you for pointing out but what if I want to turn the default text after the button is no longer clicked ?

Comment: @noone432423 no longer clicked? do you mean no longer focused since click is an event and can not be undone once generated.

Comment: nope i explained it wrong. Actually when once the button is clicked - text is changed then when the mouse is no longer over the button or user is click ing outside of the button, I want the default text to be returned and then when the user again click it - the same process to occur.

Comment: @noone432423 updated the solution for the desired behavior.  Hope this helps.